# Netsuite: Sending email from custom record

Tags: email, netsuite, record

I have create a custom record in netsuite to manage certain activities.

I would like to make use of the "sending email" from records functionality which I have vendors/customers/transactions.
However this is not available. Is there a way to add this functionality to this record?

Comment: I've never seen an "easy" way to do this.  But there are workarounds.  You can try: Workflows, (user event script) to create a "Send Email" button,  Create a (suitelet) button/custom action on the custom record that would redirect the user to a Netsuite looking page that could prompt for To, From, Body, Subject, etc.  Are you familiar with either workflows or suitescripts?

Comment: I have found it. It is called "mailmerge" on the custom record. This will show the message tab and functionality I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-requisite: Enable Mail Merge feature under Setup > Company > Enable Features > CRM tab.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Navigate to Customization > Lists, Records, & Fields > Record Types.
2. Click on the name of the record type.
   The Custom record has the following settings:

Enable Mail Merge = Yes
Access Type = Use Permissions List

Permissions tab > Custom role column is added with Edit Level of Access.

3. Log in as the Custom role and create a new Custom record/view an existing record.
   Actual Result: Mail Merge tab is not available.

To resolve the problem, perform the following:

1. Navigate to Setup > Users/Roles > Manage Roles.
2. Edit the custom role.
3. In Permission tab > Lists subtab, add the following permissions with a minimum permission level of Create.

Track Messages
Mail Merge

4. Click Save.